# TSQL: Continuous period for whole year / each month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I try to find all `Cust` who have membership for  at least for one day in each month during 2018.

I came up with solution checking  their membership at the beginning / middle / end end of each month like in snippet below, but trying to find more intelligent solution.

I know that I can use tally table for each of 365 days to check this but probably there is more elegant solution ? I'm bit new to SQL, I think I'm missing something in `GROUPing` area.

In the code snippet shown below, both `Cust` have at least one day membership.

**Desired output:**

```
CustID
------
   1
  22
```

**Code:**

```
with data as 
(
    select * 
    from (values (1, 1,   '2017-12-11', '2018-01-16'),   (1, 22,  '2018-01-28', '2018-03-9' ), (1, 333, '2018-03-1', '2018-12-31') ,  -- island
                 (22, 1,  '2017-12-31', '2018-01-11'),   (22, 2,  '2017-2-11',  '2019-12-31')) as t (CustID, ContractID, StartDD, EndDD)     ---      
    )
    select 
        isdate(startDD), isdate(EndDD) 
    from 
        data
), gaps as 
(
    select  
        *,  
        datediff(day, lag(EndDD, 1, StartDD) over (partition by CustID order by StartDD), StartDD) as BreakDD          -- negative is island
    from 
        data
)
select 
    *, 
    datepart(month,StartDD) mmS , datepart(month,EndDD) mmE 
from 
    gaps 
    -- and was active any 1+ day during each of the 12 months in 2018    ????
where 
    1 = 1 
    /* and (cast('1/1/2018' as date) between StartDD and EndDD
            or cast('1/15/2018' as date) between StartDD and EndDD     
            or cast('1/31/2018' as date) between StartDD and EndDD)
       ---- etc..  for each month
       and (      cast('12/1/2018'  as date)   between  StartDD  and  EndDD 
              or  cast('12/15/2018' as date)   between  StartDD  and  EndDD  
              or  cast('12/31/2018' as date)   between  StartDD  and  EndDD  
           ) 
*/ 
--select CustID, max(BreakDD) Max_Days
--from gaps
--group by CustID
```

Comment: Give your DDL and some sample data.

Comment: this is version with tally :       select  distinct custID, datepart(month,dd) -- gaps.* , t.dd 
  from gaps 
  join
 (   select top 365
       cast ( dateadd(day, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1 , '1-1-2018') as date) as dd
       from master..spt_values 
    ) t    on t.dd between StartDD and EndDD

Comment: Try my answer. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this answer.

First create a function to return all the month and year between the given dates.

**Function:**

```
--SELECT * FROM dbo.Fn_GetMonthYear('2017-12-11','2018-01-16')
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.Fn_GetMonthYear(@StartDate  DATETIME,@EndDate    DATETIME)
RETURNS TABLE
AS

    RETURN(
    SELECT  DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS [Month]
            ,DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, x.number, @StartDate)) AS [Year]
    FROM    master.dbo.spt_values x
    WHERE   x.type = 'P'        
    AND     x.number <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, @StartDate, @EndDate)
    )
```

**Table Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE #t(CustID INT, ContractID INT, StartDD date, EndDD date)

INSERT INTO #t values (1, 1,   '2017-12-11', '2018-01-16'),   (1, 22,  '2018-01-28', '2018-03-9' ), (1, 333, '2018-03-1', '2018-12-31') ,  -- island
                 (22, 1,  '2017-12-31', '2018-01-11'),   (22, 2,  '2017-2-11',  '2019-12-31')
```

Here is the **T-SQL Query** for your requirement.

```
SELECT CustID
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT [Month]) NoOfMonths
FROM(
    SELECT * 
    FROM #t t
    CROSS APPLY dbo.Fn_GetMonthYear(StartDD,EndDD)
    )D
WHERE [Year] = 2018
GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Month])=12
```

**Result:**

```
CustID  NoOfMonths
1       12
22      12
```

Comment: Thanks D!!! your Fn_GetMonthYear is user specific, and looks like tally table , right ? can you advice what is output of your fn_, or adjust it to generic tally I pasted before. Tx again

Comment: @Mich28, Yes its like tally table or Numbers table.

Comment: @Mich28, Is this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

> find all Cust who have membership for at least for one day in each
>   month during 2018

I think this mean that data must be present between `'2018-01-01'` and `'2018-12-31'` for each `custid`.

```
CREATE TABLE #t(CustID INT, ContractID INT, StartDD date, EndDD date)

INSERT INTO #t values (1, 1,   '2017-12-11', '2018-01-16'),   (1, 22,  '2018-01-28', '2018-03-9' ), (1, 333, '2018-03-1', '2018-12-31') ,  -- island
 (22, 1,  '2017-12-31', '2018-01-11'),   (22, 2,  '2017-2-11',  '2019-12-31')

declare @From Datetime='2018-01-01'
declare @To datetime='2018-12-31'

;with CTE as
(
select CustID,min(StartDD)StartDD
,max(EndDD)EndDD
from #t
group by CustID
)
select CustID,StartDD
,EndDD
from CTE
where StartDD<=@From and EndDD>=@To
```

This script is not tested across all sample data.
But logic is clear.So it can be corrected accordingly.

So tell for what sample data it is not working.

Comment: Thank yuou D and all